# How to insert a document in MongoDB with one of fields of type ObjectId in Mulesoft Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mongodb, mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

I am trying to insert a document in MongoDB collection with one of the fields of type ObjectId referring to a document in another collection. Refer to the following as an example:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d9b5191cbab733354f8345b"),
    "accountBalance": 1234.0,
    "pinCounter": 3,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "pinNumber": "1234",
    "accountType": "CURRENT",
    "customerId": ObjectId("5d96e3bd1c9d4400005cbb23")
}
```

The _id field is generated by MongoDB while customerId (*5d96e3bd1c9d4400005cbb23 in above example*) is provided in the request.
But when trying to map the data in the above format by appending the string "ObjectId(" is unsuccessful as in that case the field is inserted as as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the format to use for ObjectId:

```
  "_id" : {
        "\$oid": "5d9b5191cbab733354f8345b"
  }
```

So full DW script would look something like:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "_id" : {
       "\$oid": "5d9b5191cbab733354f8345b"
    },
    "accountBalance": 1234.0,
    "pinCounter": 3,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "pinNumber": "1234",
    "accountType": "CURRENT",
    "customerId": {
       "\$oid": "5d96e3bd1c9d4400005cbb23"
    }
}
```